# Return a generic pair

Tags: java, generics, instance

I'm trying to create a program which contains a generic method, which contains a type parameter. It should return an instance of the class Pair. I'm not sure how i can return a Pair. The code i have is below:

```
public class MinMaxArray
{
  public static <ArrayType extends Comparable<ArrayType>>
                ArrayType getMinMax(ArrayType[] anArray)
            throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
    try
    {


  ArrayType resultMin = anArray[0];
      ArrayType resultMax = anArray[0];
      for (int index = 1; index < anArray.length; index++)
        if (result.compareTo(anArray[index]) < 0) 
          result = anArray[index];
        if (result.compareTo(anArray[index]) > 0)
          result = anArray[index];


  return resultMin;
  return resultMax;
}//try

    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array must be non-empty", e); }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array must exist", e); }
  }//getMinMax
}//class MinMaxArray
```

Pair class Code:

```
//Two onjects grouped into a pair.
public class Pair<FirstType, SecondType>
{
  //The first object.
  private final FirstType first;

  //The second object.
  private final SecondType second;

  //Constructor is given the two objects.
  public Pair(FirstType requiredFirst, SecondType requiredSecond)
  {
    first = requiredFirst;
    second = requiredSecond;
  }//Pair



  //Return the first object.
  public FirstType getFirst()
  {
    return first;
  }//GetFirst


  //Return the second object.
  public SecondType getSecond()
  {
    return second;
  }//GetSecond

}//class Pair
```

I'm not sure how i can get the resultMax and resultMin to return as a Pair. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
public static <ArrayType extends Comparable<ArrayType>>
            Pair<ArrayType, ArrayType> getMinMax(ArrayType[] anArray) {
    ...
    return new Pair<ArrayType, ArrayType>(resultMin, resultMax);
}
```

Comment: Pavlol, in order to test it, in the main method of the test program, could i have something like: `String[] aStringArray = { "hello", "what", "is", "your", "name" }`

Comment: Sure, why not go ahead and try?

Comment: @Pavlov I'm trying to return the min and max values,but i am getting this as the output: `Pair@10385c1`                                                         the code i have in the main method for test is: `String[] aStringArray = { "the", "cat", "vaporised", "on", "the", "mat" };
    Pair minMaxInAStringArray = MinMaxArray.getMinMax(aStringArray);
    System.out.println(minMaxInAStringArray);`                           not sure what the problem is??

Comment: You should define `public String toString()` on `Pair` to print it nicely. Like this: `return "[first=" + first + ", second=" + second + "]";`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
return new Pair<ArrayType, ArrayType>(resultMin, resultMax);
```

IMHO I would use

```
return new ArrayType[] { resultMin, resultMax };
```

---

or you could add a factory method to Pair class

```
public static <FirstType, SecondType> Pair<FirstType, SecondType> of(FirstType first, SecondType second) {
      return new Pair<FirstType, SecondType>(first, second);
}
```

then you can write

```
return Pair.of(resultMin, resultMax);
```

Comment: I need to use an instance of Pair, don't have a choice, so I'll try the first one. Thanks

Comment: You could add a factory method to make it nicer. ;)

Comment: I've never heard of a factory method, sounds interesting, I'll have a look into it :)

Comment: It saves you having to write the types when the compiler can infer them.

Comment: +1 for the factory method.  I do think the pair class smells like object denial...